# How to execute first simple PHP api example using Xcode

Tags: php, ios, nsurlconnection, nsjsonserialization

This is my first API that I am calling from a demo iOS app. I just want to get the simple sentence I wrote in the php back to a label.

However the dictionary result is null when I get it in the app. How does this work?
***Corrected, code below works but not very secure

PHP file:

```
index.php hosted on localhost using XAMPP (http://localhost/tutorials/index.php) if I echo "hi"; it shows on the page so the server is working. 



 <?php 
if(function_exists($_GET['fe'])) {
   $_GET['fe']();
}
    function getLabel(){
        $response['name']="Hello first API ever";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Now in Xcode I have:

```
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
        //Main parse

        //Web data
        NSDictionary*data=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
        NSString*label=[data valueForKey:@"name"];

        _answer.text=label;

    }

    -(void)getData{

        NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/tutorials/index.php?fe=getLabel"];
        NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (connection) {
            webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        }
    }

//Clear response
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [webData setLength:0];
}

    //Append data
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
        [webData appendData:data];
    }

    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
        //Main parse

        //Web data

        NSDictionary*data=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
        NSString*label=[data valueForKey:@"name"];

        _answer.text=label;

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you also implementing connection:didReceiveResponse: and connection:didReceiveData:?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't pass nil for the error parameter. It's there for a reason. So use it, then check if data == nil, and if it is, log the error.

Comment: Ok, added an error to track. Is the URL correct? how do you add a function to the url?

Comment: So did you get an error? I have no idea whether your URL is correct, but the error should say "bad url" if it is. I don't know what you mean by "add a function to the url"

Comment: Yes, then I added the if to the php and changed the url and it worked, however I don't think that is the best approach? also what if I want to send a parameter? How do I do that in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's your connection:didReceiveData: method? It should be appending the received data to webData.

Comment: Just added it along with the other methods